# Why is being logged in not obvious?

Tags: support, login

Several times I have tried to comment on a question in the Mathematica Forum and learned only from the lack of response that I was no longer logged in, but then I went to log in (having to leave my page) and I was apparently re-logged in automatically.

How about some more obvious indication of when one is or is not logged in? Most pages present your name at the top of the page when you are logged in.

Answer (score 7):

We show your avatar, reputation, and badges in the top bar when you're logged in. For example:

[image]

Compare with the anonymous view:

[image]

Comment: Good to know. I never noticed it before.